# The following code doesn't works in IE but in opera and mozilla

Tags: javascript

This is the form

```
<form action="post" name="default_form">
    <input type="hidden" value="d" name="def" />
    <div id="load_result"></div>
  </form>
```

But the following code doesn't works in IE but properly works in mozilla,opera

```
var body = document.forms.default_form.serialize();
```

Any idea?

Comment: I assume you're using the jquery serialize() method? Could we see your script?

Comment: You've got ACTION confused with METHOD.  It should be something like `<form action="http://example.com/form-handler-file.php" method="post" name="default_form">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `form` element does not have a `serialize()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement).

It isn't in the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) either.

If you are talking about jQuery's `serialize()`, then you need to wrap the matched set with the jQuery object `$(document.forms.default_form)` or even `$('form[name="default_form"]')`.

Comment: @Ashitha Create your own code to serialize the form or use a library that can do it, such as jQuery.